# Writing to a file in Unicode

Tags: c, unicode

I am having some problems writing to a file in unicode inside my c program. I am trying to write a unicode Japanese string to a file. When I go to check the file though it is empty. If I try a non-unicode string it works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
FILE* f;
f = _wfopen(COMMON_FILE_PATH,L"w");
fwprintf(f,L"日本語");
fclose(f);
```

Oh about my system:
  I am running Windows. And my IDE is Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: I am posting this as a comment rather than an answer, because I don't know beans about C, but I wonder if your source code is in UTF-8, and the compiler thinks it's ASCII.

Comment: No I don't think that's the case. The compiler knows it is UTF-8, I made sure of it :p

Comment: OK. It was worth a shot anyway. :-)

Comment: A similar question came up recently, I think yesterday. The answer was that fwprintf doesn't convert the Unicode to single-byte properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might need to add the encoding to the mode.  Possibly this:

```
f = _wfopen(COMMON_FILE_PATH,L"w, ccs=UTF-16LE");
```

Comment: Thanks .. this worked. But that creates an additional question. I actually wanted this so that I could be able to write unicode to files generally. Japanese was just an example. 

This will work for all unicode supported languages, correct?

Comment: Correct.  It should not be language dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the same with `fopen()` works for me here.  I'm using Mac OS X, so I don't have `_wfopen()`; assuming `_wfopen()` isn't returning bad stuff to you, your code should work.

Edit: I tested on cygwin, too - it also seems to work fine.

Comment: Didn't work for me :( , _wfopen returns a normal FILE* pointer.

I am running Windows. And my IDE is Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find a reference to _wfopen on either of my boxes, I however don't see why opening it with fopen should cause a problem, all you need is a file pointer.

What matters is if or not C recognizes the internal Unicode's values and pushes those binary values to the file properly.

Try just using fopen as Carl suggested, it should work properly.

Edit: if it still doesn't work you may try defining the characters as their integer values and pushing them with fwprintf(), I know that's cumbersome and not a good fix in the long run, but it should work as well.