# How to preserve Japanese characters in a plain text file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

My C++ program is built in Visual Studio 2010 with the UNICODE option turned ON. The program collects CString data via a dialog, and writes lines to a plain text (.TXT) file. When I look at the file in a hexadecimal editor, it has clearly been written using 16-bit encoding. But most of the time, any Japanese characters that are written to the file are translated to 0x003E, a question mark, even on a Windows system configured to have a Japanese language interface. Sometimes (this is what I really don't understand) I get files from customers that are correctly encoded. All characters are 16-bit; all the Roman characters in the file have 0x00 in the high byte, but the Japanese characters use all 16 bits. This is what I want to have happen all the time.

I usually use TextWrangler to display these files on a Mac (OS X 10.10.3) when I receive them. The good ones look fine when I tell TextWrangler to open them using Shift-JIS encoding. But most of the ones I receive from Japan have question marks where Japanese characters should appear.

What can I do to make sure that Japanese characters are not destroyed when I write the file?

---

Also, I know the data are good coming from the Cstrings that I fetch from the dialog class. Some of them are stored using `AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileString()` and they are just fine; I am able to fetch them back and all the Japanese is still Japanese.

---

Here is some of the code I use to write the TXT file:

```
FILE    *f;
f   =   _tfopen(fullpath, _T("w"));
if (!f)
{
    SAY(_T("File creation error"));
    return;
}
_ftprintf(f, _T("%s\n"), m_3);
_ftprintf(f, _T("%s\n"), m_4);
_ftprintf(f, _T("%s\n"), m_5);
fclose(f);
```

That's pretty vanilla code. `m_3` thru `m_5` here are Cstring variables, and definitely wchar_t. Where are my data getting trashed and what can I do about it?

Comment: Are you sure _UNICODE is defined in your code ?  Have you tried with fwprintf ?

Comment: Yes, UNICODE is definitely defined, and _ftprintf is a macro that maps to fwprintf. There is no doubt that I'm writing 16-bit characters.

Comment: If you debug your app, how does the buffer look like in memory?

Comment: The buffer contains proper Unicode characters, for example: b4 30 b8 30 e9 30. (Little-endian)

Comment: In addition, the debugger built into Visual Studio does display the Japanese characters I expect to see. The string in the comment above is "ゴジラ".

Comment: I wish I had found this answer before I posted a question. The first answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427316/writing-to-a-file-in-unicode seems to have fixed the problem. Now I'm curious why some customers got good files and others got garbage.

Comment: There's a difference between `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE`.  The latter is for the run-time libraries, which is where `_ftprintf` comes from.  At some point, for at least some of your users, the code page is coming into play.  For others, you're getting UTF-16.